# Java Instantiate All Classes

Tags: java, instantiation

How does one **instantiate all classes** in a program, that are in **different packages** and **haven't already been instantiated**?

Comment: What do you mean by *instantiate all classes*? Do you mean create instance of class like `new SomeClass()`? If yes then how should your code react if `SomeClass` will not have any public constructor, of is it will contain only constructors with arguments? Which constructor should we use and which parameters should we pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only instantiate instance of a Class.

You can initialise a Class by attempting to access it. e.g.

```
Class.forName("mypackage.MyClass");
```

You can scan your class path to find all the classes in a package and load them this way.

Note: while you can do this, it is highly unlikely to be a good idea.  There is usually a better alternative.

Comment: has given you both the answer you thought you wanted AND the answer you need. Don't do it. Really.

Comment: Usually we use words "load class", not "instantiate". Probably asker don't understand his-own question?

Comment: Well, I asked because in a game that I am creating, the display freezes the first time you click a certain button that triggers the loading of a few classes for the first time, so I wanted to pre-load them beforehand, after setting things up.

Comment: Yeah, it's a term that I've picked up on the web. From what I know, it means to load the class and its statics

Comment: @user5204762 You can pre-load the specific code which you trigger on a button. The best option though is to work out why it takes so long first before jumping to a solution.